# Model validation not being recognized-Max # of players on a team

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

So I have a softball team, and players on that team. I want to have it so you can only add a certain numbers of player to a team (max 3). In my team.rb file, I have:

```
has_many :players
validates :team, :length => {:maximum => 3}
```

The app isn't failing, but it isn't recognizing the 3 player limit either.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is team? Is it an association? An array? Please add the data model stuff to your question.

Comment: Well it's an association isn't it?? I am very new to this. Havent created any arrays, and I built this app using rails g scaffold. So I just add players by typing in their information: player name, jersey number, and which team they want to be on (using collection_select). The player.rb model file uses belongs_to :team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, not sure if there is an easier way to do it. Had to make a custom model validator

```
validate :maxplayers

def maxplayers
    unless team.players.count < 3
    errors.add(:base, "You have reached team capacity")
  end
end
```

Note this is in player.rb, and for some reason errors.add_to_base would not work. 
Also note it is validate, not validates.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (if I get it right!) is to avoid that more than 3 players are associated with a team but it's not what you wrote.

The length validators check a field length so if for example you have a Player model with a name field you can force a maximum name length this way:

```
# In the Player model
validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 30}
```

What you want to do is harder, you have to check that in the DB for every team there are at maximum 3 players, probably you have to use model hooks...(I'm a newbie too!)

Comment: Well that's just maximum NAME length. If I do the above (which I just tried), it's going to just make the max length 30 characters. Not worried at all about length of the player name. I mean, :length in ruby is tough to wrap your head around I guess. I tried :length => { :size => 3 } but that doesn't work.

Comment: I know you didn't worried about player name, it was just an explanation of how length validates work: it refers to a single field not to the number of current associations [1].

Is the code you wrote in the app/models/team.rb file right? And you have a Player model too in app/models/player.rb right?

[1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length

Comment: Yup have a player model. belongs_to :team :) So I'm looking for a diff validation to use, what in the world would I use?

Comment: I'm trying with a custom validator and I think it could work, I will let you know ;)

Comment: Uh oh, CUSTOM validator? :) Appreciate it. You would think there would be a 'normal' validator for something this easy? :x

Comment: It's easy from the team point of view since you have the players list and you can probably check the length (have you tried this? `validates :players, :length => {:maximum => 3}`)
But from the player point of view you have to check if the team you attach to him is already full on save.

Comment: Yep tried validates :players, :length => {:maximum => 3}. App still works just not recognizing that validation.

Comment: I've searched here (in StackOverflow) and there are several solutions to this problem [1].
But I've not convinced, from what I've seen all these solutions call a method that check the size of our team.players array and in case it exceed this method set an error into errors[:base].
What not convince me is  the fact this is done just in a side and on player save nothing is done so theoretically a team with 4 players can't be saved but a new player can be associated to a full team...mah...

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+validate+number+of+associated+objects&submit=search

Comment: ...BTW try to read the official Rails guide about validations, maybe you find a smarter answer

[1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html